# Calling boost::python::object as function in separate thread

Tags: c++, python, multithreading, boost

I am trying to wrap some c++ functionality into python with the help of boost::python. I have some trouble getting a particular callback mechanism to work. The following code snippet explains what I am trying to do:

```
//c++ side
class LoopClass {

    public: 
    //some class attributes

    void call_once(std::function const& fun) const;
};

void callOnce(LoopClass& loop, boost::python::object const& function) {

    auto fun = [&]() {
        function();
    };

    loop->call_once(fun);
}

boost::python::class_<LoopClass>("LoopClass")
     .def("call_once", &callOnce);


//python side
def foo():
    print "foo"    

loop = LoopClass()
loop.call_once(foo)
```

**Here is the deal**: The function `call_once()` takes a `std::function` and puts it in a queue. LoopClass maintains an eternal loop which is run in a separate thread and, at a certain point, processes the queue of stored callback functions. To tread a `boost::python::object` as a function, the cast operator has to be called explicitly. This is why I didn't wrap `call_once()` directly but wrote the little conversion function `callOnce()` which forwards the cast operator call through a lambda.

Anyhow, when I try to run this code, accessing the `boost::python::object` fails with a segmentation fault. I guess it's just not that easy to share python objects between to threads. But how can this be done?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Update**

I tried to follow the advice of @JanneKarila

> See [Non-Python created threads](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads). –  Janne Karila

I guess this is the right point to find a solution, but unfortunately I am not able to figure out how to apply it.

I tried

```
void callOnce(LoopClass& loop, boost::python::object const& function) {

    auto fun = [&]() {
        PyGILState_STATE gstate;
        gstate = PyGILState_Ensure();

        function();

        PyGILState_Release(gstate);
    };

    loop->call_once(fun);
}
```

which doesn't work. Am I missing something or just too dumb?

Comment: See [Non-Python created threads](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/init.html#non-python-created-threads).

Comment: @JanneKarila Thanks for your reply! I updated my post and added the code I tried to use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you called PyEval_InitThreads(); ?

If so maybe this http://www.codevate.com/blog/7-concurrency-with-embedded-python-in-a-multi-threaded-c-application piece can help?